# outlook 2010 showing Â ÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂ for all my replied emails!

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

every email I replied shows

> ÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂÂ  or â€¦

for line breaks, !s or 's.

It seems it has something to do with html format, I changed the option "compose messaged in this format:" to "rtf" but that didn't help. The outlook still replies email in html format.

Any helps?`

Comment: Have you tried setting the encoding to Unicode?

Comment: Interestingly, I uncheck the option "Automatically select encoding for outgoing messages" and it seems the unrecognized characters are gone. But still, the reply is in HTML format by default.